# using SQL IN clause to select specific number

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I express if I want to select for example account numbers where
7th digit of an account number is IN(2,3,4). Let's say account number has 10 digits in total.

Comment: Is the *number* a *number* or a **string**. It is hard to answer before you clarifies. I assume you are speking about *numbers*, becouse for *string* the answer is trivial, so you should further specifiy if you consider only interegs or if the number can have also the decimal part.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - ever seen an account number that is a *number* with a decimal part?

Comment: @mathguy - I've never seen an account number with a decimal, but I've seen lots of tables where an account "number" was defined as NUMBER.  Same for Social Security "numbers" and telephone "numbers".  It's poor design, but it happens a lot.  And for the OP, the solution depends on the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(account_number, '^.{6}[234]')
```

Answer (score 0):

An other possible regular expression is:

```
where regexp_like(account_number, '^\d{6}[234]\d{3}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR` to get the 7th digit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR( account_number, 7, 1 ) IN ( '2', '3', '4' )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( account_number ) AS
SELECT 1234567890 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2222222222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3333333333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444444444 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5555555555 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | ACCOUNT_NUMBER |
> | -------------: |
> |     2222222222 |
> |     3333333333 |
> |     4444444444 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ad916bf42cbffb7d82be5a858ab92af)*